# which octal value marks the start of a program in ubuntu/why?

Tags: linux, unix, ubuntu, system

I'm reading the somewhat dated (though still quite good) "The Unix Programming Environment" by Kernighan and Pike. On page 46, in a description of the "file" program, which guesses a file's filetype, the authors claim that executable files are marked by the octal bit "410" in their beggining, ie an od call on a program would yield

```
000000 000410 .....etc
.... etc
```

.

However, when I call od on executables in my modern installation they do not start with 000410. They do, however, all seem to start with the following string of bytes (I od'd two C programs and a haskell program)

```
0000000 042577 043114 000402 000001 000000 000000 000000 000000
0000020 000002 000076 000001 ....
```

after that the files differ.

I was wondering if I have indeed found the sequence of bytes that acts as the "this is an executable" byte in ubuntu, and why today's byte-start-thingie conventions are different.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your book describes [COFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/COFF) executables. Most Linux distributions use [ELF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) files these days.